# Continues columns in a csv-file with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, export-to-csv

I have a Problem with continues writing my datas in a csv-file. I want a program that detects, if there is a csv-file for my measurements-data. If not it would be generated. When the csv-file is new generated the datas are written in the csv-file on the column after the header with the variable `cycle = 0`.

If the csv-file exists, the datas should be written continuously after the last line of the csv. Also the variable `cycle` should continue.

I have written a program that can detect if there is a file or not but with the continuously lines I have problems.
I hope someone can help me.

```
# mes = Array with 20 spaces filled with the Numbers 0-19

date = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

def write(cycle, mes):

    if os.path.exists('/home/pi/Documents/Ventilatorprüfstand_Programm/out.csv') is True: #does the out.csv existate?
        print("Do something")
        out = open('out.csv', 'w')
        data = [[cycle, mes[0],mes[1],mes[2],mes[3],mes[4],mes[5],mes[6],mes[7],mes[8],mes[9],mes[10],mes[11],mes[12],mes[13],mes[14],mes[15],mes[16],mes[17],mes[18],mes[19], date]]
        line = cycle+1    
        for row in data:
            for line in row:
                out.write('%s;' % line)
            out.write('\n')   
        out.close()

    else:
        print("Do another something")
        header = lookuptable.names()
        out = open('out.csv', 'w')
        for row in header:
            for column in row:
                out.write('%s' % column)
            out.write('\t')
        out.write('\n')

        data = [[cycle, mes[0],mes[1],mes[2],mes[3],mes[4],mes[5],mes[6],mes[7],mes[8],mes[9],mes[10],mes[11],mes[12],mes[13],mes[14],mes[15],mes[16],mes[17],mes[18],mes[19], date]]


        for row in data:
            for column in row:
                out.write('%s;' % column)
            out.write('\n')
        out.close()`
```

Comment: What is "continues"? A product or service or piece of software? Or do you mean the verb participle "continued"? Or the adjective "continuous"?

Comment: I mean I have a csv-file with 5 rows and 4 columns . The first row is the column number called cycle it starts with 0. Now i need to add columns below the existing ones. The variable cycle count up.

Comment: is the cycle actually the line number? or many lines could have the same cycle? and do you always know the last written cycle, or do you want to read it from the file before adding the new data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When opening the file with `open()` there is [the option 'a'](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) to append the new lines to the end:

> 'a'   open for writing, appending to the end of the file if it exists

Here is an example using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html) Python standard library:

```
import csv
import os
import random

headers = ['cycle', 'date', 'speed', 'temp', 'power']

new_data = [[random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(2)]
date = '00/01/02'
cycle = 1

#  Copy the data and include the date and the cycle number:
full_rows = [ [cycle, date, *row] for row in new_data ]

filename = 'example.csv'

# Check if the file exist, if not create the file with header
if not os.path.exists(filename):
    print('creating a new file')
    with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        csvwriter.writerow(headers)  # add the header

# Append the data to the file
with open(filename, 'a', newline='') as csvfile:  # note the 'a' option
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    csvwriter.writerows(full_rows)
```